# Showing paragraphs from other pages in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Have a word document with Heading 1 paragraphs starting on every single page.
I would like to show the Heading 1 paragraph of the NEXT page on each page, so having page X showing the Heading 1 of page X+1 in its footer.

Been trying to do this with Quick Parts > Field > StyleRef but don't succeed though.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this IF the style has outline numbering ie 1. Heading 1 text.

It also depends on your headings not changing, so this would be a step that you could do once your document is finalised, as it involves creating bookmarks and numbering them sequentially.

For each Heading 1 in your document, select the heading text (not the final paragraph mark) and create a bookmark (I used the format bkH1 for first heading, bkH2 for second heading, ... , bkH10 for tenth heading etc).

The STYLEREF field can return the paragraph number (ie not just the text).  If we know the paragraph number for the Heading 1 style on the current page, we know that the paragraph number for the Heading 1 style on the next page is that +1.  The \n switch returns the number.  The \l switch says search from bottom of current page up (as we want to find the last Heading 1 on this page so we know what highest number on this page is).

```
{ STYLEREF  "Heading 1" \l \n }
```

Because our bookmark names include the paragraph number of the heading, we can then reference the bookmark text using the number+1.  So for example, to pick up the text of the bookmark for our second heading we would use a REF field for "bkH2".

We want the "2" to be dynamic, and this can be done by using the STYLEREF field above +1.

```
{= 1 + { STYLEREF  "Heading 1" \l \n }}
```

Our REF field will use this in combination with the bkH prefix we have used.

```
{ REF "bkH{= 1 + { STYLEREF  "Heading 1" \l \n }}" }
```

The final step is to "trap" the error which occurs when we get to our last Heading 1 (because there will be no higher bookmark, eg if we have 10 headings, bkH11 won't exist).

```
{ IF { REF "bkH{= 1 + { STYLEREF  "Heading 1" \l \n }}" }="Error! Reference source not found." { REF "bkH{= { STYLEREF  "Heading 1" \l \n }}" } { REF "bkH{= 1 + { STYLEREF  "Heading 1" \l \n }}" }}
```

This means if an error occurs, we use the last heading (as we have dropped the +1 from the = field).  Alternatively you might want to have nothing appear for future pages in which case replace this true condition with "".  Otherwise, for false condition, we want to insert the next heading.